# How to interpret categorical covariate in a linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression

My categorical covariate (Ethnicity, with 6 categories) is significant. I know, Lm tests the first category (1) vs. the other categories (2,3,4,5,6). I swapped the sixth and the first category to observe the influence of the first category, but it became insignificant know.

What did I wrong? I want to know the influence of ethnicity on my regression, but hopefully it can't be, that the significancies depend on item code order.

```
x=ForkinYak


##Fixed Effects
##Covariates

CoAge = x$Age
CoVPSex = factor(x$Gender, levels = c(1,2,3))
CoEdu = factor(x$Education, levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
CoCDoc = x$Frequency
CoEth = factor(x$Ethnicity, levels = c(1,2,3,4,5))
CoPrefAlt = factor(x$Alt_Code)
CoPref = factor(x$Code)
CoEthSwapWhiteOthers = factor(x$WhiteEthnicity, levels = c(1,2,3,4,5))


Pos= factor(x$Posture)
Sex= factor(x$Sex)

contrasts(Pos) <- -1*contr.sum(2)
contrasts(Sex) <- -1*contr.sum(2)

model <- lm(Rating ~ Pos*Sex +  CoEth , data = x)
summary(model)



###Results
> model <- lm(Rating ~ Pos*Sex +  CoEth , data = x)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = Rating ~ Pos * Sex + CoEth, data = x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8534 -0.9356  0.1288  1.1599  2.6399 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.52145    0.17994  19.570  < 2e-16 ***
Pos1         0.16138    0.15689   1.029 0.305232    
SexM         0.24233    0.22481   1.078 0.282709    
CoEth2       1.63913    0.45748   3.583 0.000451 ***
CoEth3       0.90006    0.55872   1.611 0.109178    
CoEth4       1.17054    0.24559   4.766 4.21e-06 ***
CoEth5       0.12875    1.02912   0.125 0.900597    
Pos1:SexM   -0.05391    0.22520  -0.239 0.811120    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.416 on 159 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1867,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1509 
F-statistic: 5.216 on 7 and 159 DF,  p-value: 2.257e-05


model <- lm(Rating ~ Pos*Sex +  CoEthSwapWhiteOthers , data = x)
summary(model)


####Results, when Codes of 1 and 6 are swapped
> model <- lm(Rating ~ Pos*Sex +  CoEthSwapWhiteOthers , data = x)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = Rating ~ Pos * Sex + CoEthSwapWhiteOthers, data = x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8534 -0.9356  0.1288  1.1599  2.6399 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            3.65020    1.03527   3.526 0.000552 ***
Pos1                   0.16138    0.15689   1.029 0.305232    
SexM                   0.24233    0.22481   1.078 0.282709    
CoEthSwapWhiteOthers2  1.51038    1.09425   1.380 0.169438    
CoEthSwapWhiteOthers3  0.77131    1.14505   0.674 0.501540    
CoEthSwapWhiteOthers4  1.04179    1.03651   1.005 0.316379    
CoEthSwapWhiteOthers5 -0.12875    1.02912  -0.125 0.900597    
Pos1:SexM             -0.05391    0.22520  -0.239 0.811120    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.416 on 159 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1867,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1509 
F-statistic: 5.216 on 7 and 159 DF,  p-value: 2.257e-05
```

**DATA**

```
# first 20 rows

structure(list(Posture = c("Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
"Closed", "Closed"), Sex = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"
), Rating = c(5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 6, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 2, 1), Ethnicity = c(1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 
4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), WhiteEthnicity = c(5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model isn't changing if you reorder categories, only the specific contrasts for which estimates and statistical significance is being calculated. (Note the estimate for the `Pos1` coefficient doesn't change at all between models).

If there are no significant differences between one group (say group 6) and the other groups, but there are differences between those groups (groups 1 and 4) then it is likely that you don't have enough samples in group 6 to show that is different to either 1 or 4.

Neither of your models specifically tests whether 'ethnicity' has a significant effect on the outcome variable.  To test this you could compare a model with ethnicity included to a model without ethnicity to check for the improvement in fit.  For example:

```
model <- lm(Rating ~ Pos*Sex +  CoEth , data = x)
model2 <- lm(Rating ~ Pos*Sex, data = x)
anova(model, model2)
```

You should see the same results whichever order the covariate levels are in.  But the individual contrasts in the `summary.lm` output will be different.

Finally, you can use the `emmeans` package to see different contrasts from your model rather than swapping around the factor levels manually.  For example:

```
pairs(emmeans::emmeans(model, "CoEth"))
```